# Updating failed after adding shortcode

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have created a new plugin for youtube video slider. I have used below code for plugin creation. After activating this plugin, post and page update is not working. I am getting the error is "Updating failed"

I have used shortcode like this [az_youtube_slider] in my post.

Can you please anyone help me to fix the error.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Assistanz youtube slider
Plugin URI: https://www.assistanz.com/
Description: Get videos from youtube assistanz channel and slider
Version: 1.0
Author: Safia
Author URI: https://assistanz.com/
License: GPLv2 or later
Text Domain: assistanz
*/
if(!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;
function az_youtube_slider($atts, $content = null) {
  return "<p>Youtube video will come here</p>";
}

add_shortcode("az_youtube_slider", "az_youtube_slider");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Classic Editor' plugin to fix your issue also your function will not work, please update your function with below.

```
function displayDate($atts, $content = null) {
  return "<p>Youtube video will come here</p>";
}

add_shortcode("az_youtube_slider", "displayDate");
```

Comment: What is the difference between your function and OP function? I am also getting the same issue